# Stop submitting jobs when there is no data

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

I use spark streaming to get data from a queue in mq via a custom receiver. 
Javastreaming context duration is 10 seconds.
And there is one task defined for the input from queue.

In event time line in spark UI, I see a job getting submitted in each 10s interval even when there is no data from the receiver.

Is it the normal behavior or how to stop jobs getting submitted when there is no data.

```
JavaDStream<String> customReceiverStream = ssc.receiverStream(newJavaCustomReceiver(host, port)); 
JavaDStream<String> words =lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() { ... });
words.print();
ssc.start();
ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Comment: You can just filter out the RDD inside JavaDStream which are empty.

Comment: but that filtering will be done in a job right?

Comment: Yeah, the Streaming job should run all the time I guess.

Comment: no i mean there is receiving job which runs all the time. At the end of each 10 seconds, there is another job submitting to spark which process the income data within that 10s as I understand. I want to stop submitting that job if there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around
You can use livy to submit the spark jobs(use java codes instead of cli commands).
Livy job would be constantly checking a database that would have an indicator whether the data is flowing in or not.As soon as the data flow stops,change the indicator in the database and this would result in spark job being killed by the livy.(Use Livy sessions)